# Spring Security 5 sha256 encoder

Tags: spring, security, credentials, sha256

I have a problem with Spring Security 5 Basic authentication. I've configured Spring like this:

```
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("{sha256}5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Everything works great with {noop} password encoder (commented code) - I'm able to authenticate with header: Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==. But when I provide sha256 encoded password (uncommented code), I keep getting:

`org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials`

Comment: For the sha256 encryption are you also using the plain text "password" in the authentication process?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{SHA-256}
```

instead of

```
{SHA256}
```